# Publishing an asp.net mvc3 website database and all to a website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql

Just wondering is this possible : I have some local databases which run fine. If I could move them all up to a server online it would be great (with their data and all that).

Currently, what I'm doing is creating the datbaases remotely and creating the tables to match the ones on my project along with the tables then uploading using webmatrix and setting the appropriate connection string to the databases on the server (not even sure if this will work, haven't been able to test it yet).

Just wondering, since I'd potentially save a lot of time and effort, could I just move the local database online as part of the publish process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many easier ways, to mention a few:

- Backup the database (right click, all tasks, back up), then restore it on the live server. The restore will ask you for a DB name and allow you to change the default file location / name of the restored DB, so, you can restore the same backup as multiple databases
- SQL Server Imort and Export wizard, explained http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/21/sql-server-2005-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/ has the option in its choices property grid to export data as well. You can export to SQL file from local, and run the SQL file on the server.